# Составление SQL-запроса

Tags: sql, mysql

У меня есть 2 таблицы, `one` и `two`, предположим.

- В `one` есть поля `id`, `x`, `y`, `z`.
- В `two` есть поля `pid`, `stat1`, `stat2`.

Можно по значению `one.x` (которое будет ключом для поля `two.pid`) получить `stat1` и `stat2`. Это легко (`SELECT two.stat1, two.stat2 FROM one, two WHERE one.x = two.pid`), то есть элементарный JOIN.

Но мне надо несколько иное: сделать то же самое, но использовав все поля в `one`, то есть условия `one.x = two.pid`, `one.y = two.pid`, `one.z = two.pid` (на самом деле их немного больше). То есть получить `stat1`  и `stat2` для каждого из них, сохранив соответствие.

Можно ли сделать это одним запросом и как? Или всё-таки придётся просто отдельные простые JOIN'ы.

Comment: from one o
left join two t1 on (o.x=t1.pid)
left join two t2 on (o.x=t2.y)
left join ....

Comment: @alexlz, перенесите в ответ, ваш вариант наиболее подходит, но есть одно но:
я в итоге получаю что-то типа:  
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [stat1] => 1, [stat2] => 35 ) [1] => Array ( [stat1] => 6, [stat2] => 54 ) )`
То есть `[0]`-массив - это для `x` значения, `[1]` - для `y`, ну и там потом для `z` ещё. А как мне соответствие то это найти (кроме как порядком следования, что неудобно очень).

Comment: @Construct не понятна Ваша проблема. Для каждой строки из one Вы получаете от нуля до трёх строк результата. И что Вы хотите (кстати, возможные повторения можно убрать задав DISTINCT). Как узнать откуда оно приползло? Не знаю. Если нужен pid, то включите его в результат. Если Вам нужно узнать, что послужило причиной: x, y или z -- тогда добавочное поле с case.

Comment: @alexlz, дадада, чтобы я видел, к примеру, что вот эти `stat1` и `stat2` были от `x`, а вот те от `y`. Можно, конечно, просто воспользоваться порядком следования полученных рядов, но не очень удобно. Поясните, как там с `CASE`.

Comment: @Construct дополнил ответ. Может так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from one join two on two.pid in (one.x, one.y, one.z)

Upd

```
select case two.pid 
    when one.x then 'x' 
    when one.y then 'y' 
    else 'z' end as t, two.stat1, two.stat2 
 from one join two on two.pid in (one.x, one.y, one.z);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большущее!)

Comment: Подумайте над тем, что будет, если в x одной строке равно y в другой. Этот запрос выдаст две строки, отличающиеся полем t (distinct дублирование не уберёт)

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо, у меня не может быть повторения там.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял:

```
SELECT two.stat1, two.stat2 FROM one, two WHERE one.x = two.pid OR one.y = two.pid OR one.z = two.pid
```

Comment: Благодарю, но не совсем то выходит.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT one.id, 
  one.x, two_x.stat1 as stat1_x, two_x.stat2 as stat2_x,
  one.y, two_y.stat1 as stat1_y, two_y.stat2 as stat2_y,
  one.z, two_z.stat1 as stat1_z, two_z.stat2 as stat2_z
FROM
  one
    left join two as two_x on one.x = two_x.pid
    left join two as two_y on one.y = two_y.pid
    left join two as two_z on one.z = two_z.pid
```

Comment: Выходит дико громоздко, с учётом того, что там 13 полей вместо `x`, `y`, `z`и примерно 7 вместо `stat1` и `stat2`.

Comment: Формулируйте тогда вопрос четче. А-ля "мне нужен простой запрос в одну строку, подойдет декартово произведение".